# Xamarin Froms XAML get color from App Resource

Tags: xamarin.forms

I made a color resource in Xamarin Forms App like this:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Name="ColorLineSeparator">#cccccc</Color>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I want to use it in MainPage.xaml like this:

```
<BoxView
            HeightRequest=".5"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            BackgroundColor="[HOW TO USE IT HERE?]"/>
```

Original WPF handle this issue something like this:

```
<Button Background="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ColorLineSeparator}" />
```

However it seems not working in Xamarin Forms Page.
It showing this error:

> No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ResourceKey', or
>   mismatching type between value and property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to declare `Application.Resources` the right way:

```
<Application ...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="ColorLineSeparator">#cccccc</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

All the resources declared this way are actually static:

```
<BoxView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorLineSeparator}"/>
```

There is a [great official article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries/) about this stuff.

P.S.: Enabling [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/) may help you to identify such mistakes in the future.

Comment: Ok it worked with both ResourceDictionary and StaticResource. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Add x:Key in your resource:

```
<Color x:Key="MyColor">#cccccc</Color>
```

and use it:

```
      <BoxView
        HeightRequest=".5"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource MyColor}"/>
```